# what's the best way to migrate k2 data joomla 2.5 to joomla 3.5

Tags: database, joomla2.5, joomla3.0, database-migration, k2

i setup my site on a dev server and upgraded to the latest joomla version and setup all kind of new modules and a new template.

i don't want to do the upgrade again on the live site and resetup everything again.

what's the best way to migrate  k2 data joomla 2.5 to joomla 3.5  ?  Data from 01/06/2016 until today including k2 images.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Just export tables in db with names #__k2_* and import them to live site. If you need export data from 01/06/2016 use sql request in phpmyadmin (for example 'SELECT * FROM `#__k2_items` WHERE `created`>`2016-05-28 00:00:00`') for each table before export. And copy folder /media/k2. It's enough, if I understand the question correctly all. Check id's